Why do the shape/fluid loaders have three levels?
In shapez 2, I don't understand why the shape and fluid loaders have three levels; it looks like they only use one of the levels to load items. When the bottom level is overloaded, it doesn't load items in the middle level, and if a new shape or fluid is added, the bottom level is replaced with the new item instead of adding the new items to the middle level.
The problem is depicted on this GIF:

The leftmost loader switches between red and green fluid, and the other two loaders can only load items on the bottom level instead of using the rest of the levels.
So I don't understand the point of having these three levels. Is it for storing more of the same item? Or is it to have three different items stored? How can I take advantage of these three levels?

Note: The "code" blocks are text that if you copy, you can directly paste into the game as a blueprint
Each "layer" represents a layer of the factory floor; and all four lanes merge/split into one/four when loading/unloading a train.


You can't mix-and-match shapes on a single layer, but if you seperate them into three layers, you can send different shapes in bulk.
As for why you can't split them... Well, you can! Except it's not very efficient, as all you've done is made three lanes of 1/3 (well, more like a 1/2 and two 1/4 lanes) efficiency each.
Note: The third layer is a research unlock that is not available when you start a new game.

SHAPEZ2-1-H4sIAE5Y52YA/6STX0vDMBTFv8vBxwxMxAcDPthNYdCHss0ykT2ENdVgSEt6yxil393+wY2NbeqaQCAkv3vPucmtEEPy24d7hiCCrHBD21xDIiiNTYz7AMN0nbn2aKJIQb7DNHv5c16AudLafkHxqXItx2U/saoZnh15o4sGrLCEvGN4gxxxhhmkYFi0ubSliU5Vaekl8xvlk6kj7Z2ysfJGOULNOlgMgfkQeHQudZR5mmuXaH9MMoybO9FTNx53gU7JmOfWUEPzRSbCcwp6gvdEaFLir3mg1l+XVO+ThR066x7gyHmoU/rd9i7Ateb/7/rQrrhsdy9TXOHzoFBi6Bc5FePvtVo1vWic8ttY+8K0vdc2aF1/CyDAAEQ8nvKsAwAA$

As for why it's like that?
Well...

A shape harvester with four extensions create four sets of harvester nodes.
Each set of four small harvester building can fully saturate a belt.
Four sets of harvester nodes (16 harvester buildings) can fully saturate a layer.
Combine three of these fully kitted buildings together and you can saturate all three layers!


SHAPEZ2-1-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$

Now, without making spaghetti factories, can you process them in as neat of a formation as possible?
Either way, if you haven't unlocked trains yet (or cramming trains into your factory is not practical), at least you've now you've got a more efficient way of transporting shapes long distances using 1/3 as many platform units with only belts.

I expect there is a way to split exactly 1/3 to each layer, if there's some need for that--the factorio balancers book can probably be adapted.

@Hearth It depends on how you split it. If you turn it into a 3-way intersection, then it's 1/3 each way. Otherwise, what you're actually doing is splitting one into two halves, then splitting the other half into quarters.
